# How can I insert my own JavaScript into page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Internet Explorer as the default browser. (Firefox is not an option).

There are some web apps that I like but whose layout and workflow does not quite agree with me.

Given that I am merely a visitor to the website, is it possible to insert [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) into the webpages I'm browsing so that I can re-arrange the web content and call the javascript functions included? Sort of like using jQuery as a scripting language for IE?

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox we have Greasemonkey. [Another project](http://www.gm4ie.com/) was inspired by it.

Answer (score 1):

As Ignacio notes, using Greasemonkey is often an approach people use to manipulate the content of a website only for their own client.

[Getting Greasemonkey into Internet Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/266509/greasemonkey-for-ie8) has been discussed already, but to summarize:

- There is now a Greasemonkey equivalent for Internet Explorer, called [Trixie](http://www.bhelpuri.net/Trixie/).
- Then there's [IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/), which provides similar functionality.