# Greasemonkey for IE (8)?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, greasemonkey

I've been searching some of the morning today and am unable to find a 'Greasemonkey' type program for IE8.

I have a horrendous 'Incident Monitor' ticket app at my company and it looks like it was developed for tiny screens and IE5, I would like to get some control over this mess.

Greasemonkey would work but app won't allow FF, one of those IE-only things.

I'm looking to be able to modify some styles / add to styles / view.

Answer (score 5):

It's true that Trixie has been developed a long time ago but it actually works with IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10 and even IE11.
I've been using it for a long time.

Some time ago the website went down but you can download it from my Dropbox: [Trixie 0.2.3.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61389127/Trixie%200.2.3.zip)

To operate it:

1. put your userscript in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Bhelpuri\Trixie\Scripts\` folder (it contains some samples you can start with)
2. restart IE or go to "Tools" -> "Trixie Options" menu and click "Reload Scripts" button (no need to restart IE)

Also you can enable/disable scripts using checkboxes.
That's pretty much all you need to know.

NOTE: One issue though, the script is not executed on page refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), you need to click on the address bar and hit Enter (not a deal breaker, at least for me).

Comment: Dziekuje Piotrze ;)

Answer (score 4):

A Trixie Clone has been developed, that works with IE11 on Windows 8:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/trixiewpf45/

It is not the simplest to use, i.e. if you develop userscripts you have to reload them via the Trixie settings panel to refresh the scripts.

Blurb from site:

> Several years ago, there was Trix on http://www.bhelpuri.net/Trixie/. 
>     But there is no official sites, only a copy of Ver.0.2.3 could be gotton.
>    I got a trouble after I installed IE11.
>    I've tried to solve my problem making own Greasemonkey and got it.
>    I've looking for the way how my Greasemonkey could be applied on IE11.
>    Then I got Trixie binary and started to rewrite it.