# How to install a UserScript in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: installation, internet-explorer-9, userscripts

Is there any way to install a UserScript or GreaseMonkey script in IE9?

I know that [Trixie](http://www.bhelpuri.net/Trixie) used to be able to provide this capability but it doesn't seem to work in IE9 at all.

Comment: The Trixie site is either broken or dead. I can't find a newer site either.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/). I've used it in the past, and it worked pretty well with UserScripts. Despite its name, it is compatible with IE9.

Comment: I know this was posted in '11' but the site is broken and this doesn't seem to work with IE9 anymore. Any other alternatives?

Comment: I haven't been using IE too much, I'm mostly on Linux nowadays. Maybe someone else can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Trixie does work with IE9 (and others).
Check my answer here: [Greasemonkey for IE (8)?](https://superuser.com/questions/266509/greasemonkey-for-ie8)

As for IE7Pro I've been using it with IE7 and liked it, but it took a long time for it to become compatible with IE8 and I stopped using it then.